# Addressing leg discrepancy with orthotics in tight running shoes

Tags: running, shoes

I've got a leg length discrepancy (left leg is 14 mm shorter), and I've been advised to use orthotics. The thing is, I love my Nike React Infinity Run Flyknit 3, and they fit snugly. Wondering how to incorporate orthotics without making my left foot feel cramped. Any general advice for this scenario?

Additionally, I would appreciate insights into general practices for individuals dealing with leg length discrepancies and using orthotics in tightly fitting shoes.

P.D.: Please let me know if this is suited for this website, or should I post in other SE site